# FPDF return the files on PHP instead on PDF when I use a POST FORM

Tags: php, fpdf, php-8

I am working on a generate PDF button that it's a POST method and this POST opens to you a new window opens a PDF. (Until here all nice). But when I try to download instead the name report.pdf appears report.php.

Do you know what can it happening?

Here I left to you the code what I output FPDF:

```
header("Content-type:application/pdf");
$filename = 'Report -'.date("d-m-Y").'.pdf';
$pdf->Output($filename,'I');
```

And this is what happens when I click to download on the PDF

[image]

Answer (score 0):

It's not completely clear to me, what you mean by "*when I click to download on the PDF*". Maybe it works with a Content-Disposition-Header:

```
$filename = 'Report -'.date("d-m-Y").'.pdf';
header("Content-type:application/pdf");
header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="'.$filename.'"');
$pdf->Output($filename,'I');
```